# Received orders with a duplicate order ids

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-duplication

We have received 2 orders with the same order id.
Like We have 2 orders with the following order Ids:

## 000001256

## 000001256

How is this possible?
Does anyone has faced this type of issue OR any idea on this case?
We are using Magento ver: 2.1.2

Note => That issue we faced one day only and on that day we have server space issue so is there any relation between Server space and Duplicate order Ids issue?

Appreciated any thought from the community!

Comment: you can use any third party payment extension in checkout?

Comment: Are you using multiple stores with same prefix?

Comment: @RakeshDonga We have onestepcheckout.

Comment: @SukumarGorai We have multi-store but with different prefix.

Comment: @jack you can create observer and duplicate entry stopping

Comment: @RakeshDonga actually this issue is not reproducible now what I want now just what to know the possibility how this may happen?

Comment: @Jack possibility you have installed third part extension? and created order this payment method